# Why do datasheets sometimes use fractions of a microfarad or tens of thousands of picofarads instead of nanofarads?

Tags: capacitor, datasheet, terminology

[This datasheet](https://download.mikroe.com/documents/add-on-boards/click/load_cell_5_click/load-cell-5-click-schematic-v100.pdf) for a mini dev board, as an example, denotes eg C1 as 0.1µF, and C6 as 10000pF, instead of 100nF and 10nF, respectively. This is something I've noticed in several datasheets at various times. Is there a reason some manufacturers would avoid the usage of nF as a unit in this manner?

Comment: I've often wondered this as well. It's not just datasheets--if you look at capacitor listings on Digikey or Mouser, many of them will list capacitances of "10000 pF" or "0.22 μF" instead of "10 nF" or "220 nF".

Comment: Nanofarads are a relatively recent invention - when I was a lad we only had microfarads and micro-microfarads.

Comment: It may correspond to the print/markings on the capacitor.

Comment: It is a historical thing.  See:  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/245450/why-are-capacitors-often-not-labeled-using-engineering-notation-1-999

Comment: I've always used uF and pF, and sometimes F in discussions, for over 60 years.  For some reason, it seems like the industry coalesced  around suffixes that differed by 10^6.  I do not remember seeing nF being used at all back in the early days.

Comment: But, on the other hand units of time differ by a factor of 10^3 - s, ms, us, ns, ps, fs, etc.

Comment: Yep, seems like this is a duplicate, my google-fu was just off and those two questions didn't come up

Comment: @IsaacMiddlemiss - Hi, Thanks for creating an answer to capture the information from the comments. Following the protocol explained on Meta [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127781) & [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252303), I have copied the relevant info from comments and added links to the original comments & user profiles, to comply with the CC BY-SA license. I have also set it to "Community Wiki" so the answer's author doesn't get from votes from the answer (as it is an aggregation of info from other site members). The CW setting shouldn't imply easier editing here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was answered in the comments, so this answer was created to capture that information.

[Comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/668154/why-do-datasheets-sometimes-use-fractions-of-a-microfarad-or-tens-of-thousands-o/668155#comment1778675_668154) by [Peter Bennett](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/19835/peter-bennett):

> Nanofarads are a relatively recent invention - when I was a lad we only had microfarads and micro-microfarads

---

[Comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/668154/why-do-datasheets-sometimes-use-fractions-of-a-microfarad-or-tens-of-thousands-o/668155#comment1778674_668154) by [Hearth](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/57556/hearth):

> It's not just datasheets--if you look at capacitor listings on Digikey or Mouser, many of them will list capacitances of "10000 pF" or "0.22 μF" instead of "10 nF" or "220 nF".

---

[Comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/668154/why-do-datasheets-sometimes-use-fractions-of-a-microfarad-or-tens-of-thousands-o/668155#comment1778678_668154) by [user1850479](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/50290/user1850479):

> It is a historical thing.  See:  [why are capacitors often not labeled using engineering notation ? (1-999)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/245450/why-are-capacitors-often-not-labeled-using-engineering-notation-1-999)

---

**Summary**: It appears this is due to a historic naming convention, as described in [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/245450/why-are-capacitors-often-not-labeled-using-engineering-notation-1-999) and [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/95816/why-are-capacitor-sizes-rarely-expressed-in-nanofarads), with nanofarads being a more recent thing.